# Is it possible to move 2D character at a specific angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I have started developing 2D isometric game in Unity, but i'm struggling with the movement. I want to move my character at a specific angle. To be more specific with you and give you better idea what i like to achieve is to create movement like in "Bouncy Bits"

Here is a video of their gameplay: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6xA4RzuRcM&t=19s

I would love to achieve that kind of moving to my player including him to move forward alone in that same angle without me pressing any keys.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out, by giving me a code or explain me what i exactly need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Move your character on vector.forward, which is equivalent of (0, 0, 1) on the Z axis. Put your camera on that front angle how they have it. It would look the same.

Comment: Hm well yeah that's good trick if i'm building a 3D game, but is it possible to achieve it using isometric 2D sprites?

Comment: Personally I'd say that style of game would be 3D but maybe I'm wrong. I've never dealt with Isometric games so I actually don't know how that looks in the Unity Editor. Wouldn't you just be able to move at a vector of (1, -1, 0) which would create a diagonal downwards to the right?